# What is bad-tag for?

Tags: discussion

I was looking at the Tags page, and noticed a tag named [bad-tag](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/bad-tag). The tag has no tag-wiki or questions. What is it used for?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

People create tags for no reason all the time, what we do is just make sure no questions are tagged with it, and then the system will cull the unused tags regularly [every day at 3:00 UTC](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/177327/203389).